# DbProviderFactory with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I developed a `IDbConnection` utility class (`DbConnectionUtils`) to reduce boilerplate throughout the codebase.  This utility class automatically creates/disposes transactions and commands.  So any services which need to write to the database, are injected with this utility class instead of the `IDbConnection`.  While this works, the database connection is open longer than it needs to be because `IDbConnection` is injected into `DbConnectionUtils`, so the consuming class is unaware of `IDbConnection`.  In order to open and close the DB connection as needed, I came across `DbProviderFactory`.  If I were to inject `DbProviderFactory` instead of `IDbConnection` into the utility class, the utility class could create and dispose of connections, transactions, and commands after every database query.  My only concern here is when a function has multiple steps, each with its own interaction with the database.  So if a function has three steps, a DB connection would be opened and closed three times, instead of one connection which gets terminated after the class is disposed of.  I've never injected a factory into a class, is this considered a good practice when dealing with DB connections?

Original version.  One DB connection is opened throughout DbConnectionUtils lifespan

```
class DbConnectionUtils{
  private IDbConnection _connection;

  public DbConnectionUtils(IDbConnection connection){
    _connection = connection;
  }

  public invokeWithTransaction(string sql, IDictionary<string, object> parameters){
    using(var t = _connection.CreateTransaction()){
      using(var c = _connection.CreateCommand()){
        c.Transaction = t;
        // Bind parameters, invoke command, and perform additional steps...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Refactored version.  One DB connection is open and closed per query, which isn't a big deal for MyClass1, but adds overhead for MyClass2.

```
class DbConnectionUtils{
  private DbProviderFactory _connectionFactory;

  public DbConnectionUtils(DbProviderFactory connectionFactory){
    _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
  }

  public invokeWithTransaction(string sql, IDictionary<string, object> parameters){
    using(var connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection()){
      using(var t = _connection.CreateTransaction()){
        using(var c = _connection.CreateCommand()){
          c.Transaction = t;
          // Bind parameters, invoke command, and perform additional steps...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
class MyClass1 {
  private DbConnectionUtils _dbUtils;

  public MyClass1(DbConnectionUtils dbUtils) {
    _dbUtils = dbUtils;
  }

  public void CreateUser(User user){
    var sql = "insert into users ...";
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>{
      // Set parameters
    };
    _dbUtils.invokeWithTransaction(sql, parameters);
  }
}

class MyClass2 {
  private DbConnectionUtils _dbUtils;

  public MyClass2(DbConnectionUtils dbUtils) {
    _dbUtils = dbUtils;
  }

  public void SomethingComplexWithMultipleSteps(){
    var sql1 = "insert into step1 ...";
    var parameters1 = new Dictionary<string, object>{
      // Set parameters
    };
    _dbUtils.invokeWithTransaction(sql, parameters);
    // Perform additional C# steps


    var sql2 = "insert into step2 ...";
    var parameters2 = new Dictionary<string, object>{
      // Set parameters
    };
    _dbUtils.invokeWithTransaction(sql, parameters);
    // Perform additional C# steps


    var sql3 = "insert into step3 ...";
    var parameters3 = new Dictionary<string, object>{
      // Set parameters
    };
    _dbUtils.invokeWithTransaction(sql, parameters);
    // Perform additional C# steps
  }
}
```

Update: Connection Pooling

```
class DbConnectionUtils{
  private IDbConnection _connection;

  public DbConnectionUtils(IDbConnection connection){
    _connection = connection;
  }

  public invokeWithTransaction(string sql, IDictionary<string, object> parameters){
    if(_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
      _connection.Open();
    }

    using(var t = _connection.CreateTransaction()){
      using(var c = _connection.CreateCommand()){
        c.Transaction = t;
        // Bind parameters, invoke command, and perform additional steps...
        _connection.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a "it depend" kind of question based on what you actually want to happen.

Comment: Your `DBConnectionUtils` class could have a method that returns an `IDbConnection`.  Callers who want to perform multiple actions within the same connection could use this method, but would be responsible for closing/disposing the `IDbConnection`.  Callers who only perform single actions would use your existing method.  Also, you should measure performance; connection pooling may mean that the additional overhead in your `MyClass2` example is less than you think.

Comment: @Joe, I'll look into measuring the performance difference.  Is there anything conceptually wrong (bad practice, tight coupling, anti-pattern, etc) with injecting a factory into a class?

Comment: DI is pretty mainstream, so I don't thing see anything wrong with using it here.  A problem with your samples is that they own an `IDbConnection` instance, but don't implement `IDisposable`.  Your updated method should create/open/close the `IDbConnection` within the `invokeWithTransaction` method.  And a method that returns an `IDbConnection` instance would be useful for callers with more complex requirements: make siimple things easy (single action without the caller needing boilerplate code), and complex things possible (callers with multiple actions can use a `IDbConnection` instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your design approach suffers from one shortcoming. It tries to open and close DB connection every time it is needed instead of reusing connections via pooling.

The assumptions behind the above conclusions come from the following analysis: (i) your design aims at both reducing boilerplate code and at the same time achieving efficient connection management, (ii) you care about the connection being opened and closed as fast as possible. Providing that opening and closing DB connection is always an expensive action the better design would be based on connection pooling where you keep continuously a pool of connections that are permanently open and provided for use whenever such need arises. Once the connection is used it is returned immediately into the pool and is available for immediate reuse. As a result, you save on time which is spent on opening and closing the DB connection.

Comment: Well, assuming that those are ADO.NET IDbConnection, then we shouldn't forget that there is already an integrated [Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-pooling) at least for some providers, so implementing our own pooling over, for example, SqlDbConnection does not seem very useful. And even if it there is no integrated pooling for that IDbConnection(or it is some truly abstract IDbConnection), it may still end up being barely noticeable optimization for most of the real usage scenarios.

Comment: @EugenePodskal, your assumption is correct, I am using ADO.NET IDbConnection.  After reading your comments and the Connection Pooling link, I shouldn't ben worried about opening and closing DB connections multiple times.

Comment: > `assuming that those are ADO.NET IDbConnection ... there is already an integrated Connection Pooling at least for some providers` -> even if the assumption partially holds the code in the example does not indicate the type of provider nor the database it works with. Assuming, code has to be correct always at least it should check for connection pooling availability and correct behavior if not present. Otherwise, I am a bit indifferent about what is presented, at least I would not accept this code into repo I am maintaining